# content_tag outputs unexpected results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-tag

I have a method in my helper that loops through an array of activerecord objects and print the p tag for each item.

```
def tutor_work_exp(application)
        work_exps = application.work_exps
        if work_exps.present?
            work_exps.collect do |work_exp|
                content_tag :p do
                    work_exp.detail
                end
            end
        end
 end
```

I already read the rails api and somebody mentioned that I should not use the each method for content_tag, instead using the collect method. However, the result I got is an array of multiple strings like this:

```
["<p>25 years of selling stuffs</p>", "<p>15 years of selling books and electronic stuffs</p>"]
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.
Here is how I am calling the helper method in my view(I am using haml by the way):

```
.item
    .content
      .header
        %p Work Exp:
      .description.m-mini--top
        = tutor_work_exp(@application)
```

Comment: collect creates a new array with the objects.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but please see my updated question. It returns an array included the p tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem by wrapping the content_tag method inside of the concat method like this:

```
application.work_exps.each do |work_exp|
                concat(content_tag(:p, work_exp.detail))
            end
```

However, now it also prints the detail of all the activerecord objects, but I think it is another problem. 
The solution that I got is from [thoughtbot](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/nesting-content-tag-in-rails-3)

Update:
Ok, I got the reason why it also prints the object's details to the view. It is because of this line of code:

```
=tutor_work_exp(@application)
```

Basically, the each method will automatically returns the object itself that is calling it. In my case here, it is an array of activerecord objects, and the `=` will print whatever object is return and put it in the view. You can refer more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547227/ruby-on-rails-helper-prints-out-odd-stuff/43547362).

So, I change it to:

```
- tutor_work_exp(@application)
```

It works perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

`tutor_work_exp(@application)` returns an array. So use an each loop in the views to output contents of the array `tutor_work_exp(@application)`.